# How to add close icon button to mat-basic-chip in Angular Material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I created a custom styled chips list with `mat-basic-chip` (Unstyled chips) as per [official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)

**My Chips look like**
[image]

Now, I want to add close `buttons` to my chips as default `mat-chips` have
[image]

Here is the template of `mat-basic-chip`

```
<mat-basic-chip *ngFor="let signal of signals">
                    <div matLine class="text-center">{{signal .name}}</div>
                    <div matLine class="mt-sm-n1 text-center"><small>(Default)</small></div>
</mat-basic-chip>
```

As per the official docs  receives the mat-basic-chip CSS class in addition to the mat-chip class.
So, here is the CSS of .mat-basic-chip to style my custom chips:

```
.mat-basic-chip {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: right;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 1vh;
  padding: .7vh 0vh .7vh .7vh;
  margin-right: 2vh;
  margin-top:1vh;
  min-width: 15vh;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to add a remove button to the mat-basic chip

You can use the normal chip `mat-chip` with all your customizations like in the picture without changing any css.

I took the basic example of the `mat-chip` fruits. There is changed it to the following:

```
<mat-chip
  *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
  [selectable]="selectable"
  [removable]="removable"
  (removed)="remove(fruit)">
  <div>
    <div matLine>{{fruit}}</div>
    <div matLine><small>(Default)</small></div>
  </div>
  <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
```

Modified example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/mjygopomxvq

## Customize your mat-chip

**This method is officially supported and recommended. For more information look at**

- https://material.angular.io/guide/theming and
- https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Using that you can add the `color` property to make customizations for different states. For that modify the `.mat-chip.mat-custom` class whereas the `mat-custom` can be anything. Just the `mat-...` has to be the same.

SCSS

```
.mat-chip.mat-primary {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.mat-chip.mat-accent {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}

/* Your implementation from the description */

.mat-chip.mat-anything {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 1vh;
    padding: .7vh 0vh .7vh .7vh;
    margin-right: 2vh;
    margin-top:1vh;
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip color="primary" selected>Primary</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip color="accent" selected>Accent</mat-chip>
  <mat-chip color="anything" selected>
    <div>
      <div matLine>Anything</div>
      <div matLine><small>(Default)</small></div>
    </div>
    <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

[image: custom-mat-chip-image]

**DEMO for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5xq8y**

Feel free to leave some feedback.

Answer (score 4):

You can click the `view source` button in the offial docs to se how they have done it.
They add a mat-icon in the chip like this:

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
         [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
  {{fruit.name}}
  <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
```

You don't need to reinvent the wheel here and write your own icon for the remove button, it's already been done.

Take a closer look in the [offical docs](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chip-input) and press the `view source` button.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I already have tried that mat-icon for cancel but the problem is the alignment of cancel icon on my custom chip

Comment: If you setupt a stackblitz with your component i could probably correct it for you with the mat-icon if you would like.
Basic angular project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wens1w?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: One would expect the chip itself to present a delete button once `removable` is enabled (otherwise, what's the point of having a `removable` setting/property?) - anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> You can easily achieve this, I got this solution last week where i
>   need this same thing in `mat-chips`

**SCSS**

```
  .mat-chip-list-wrapper {
    margin: 1px 0 !important;
    .mat-standard-chip {
      padding: 0 $space-5 !important;
      display: flex;
      .mat-icon {
        font-size: 17px;
      }
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-chip-list class="mat-chip-list-wrapper" aria-label="Selected list">
      <mat-chip>Hello
       <mat-icon matChipRemove >cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>      
</mat-chip-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

one of solutions is to use `flexbox`.

should be something like this:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
}

.cancel-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px;
}


mat-basic-chip {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: right;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 1vh;
    padding: .7vh 0vh .7vh .7vh;
    margin-right: 2vh;
    margin-top:1vh;
    min-width: 15vh;
}
```

```html
    <mat-basic-chip *ngFor="let signal of signals">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="content">
                <div matLine class="text-center">{{signal.name}}</div>
                <div matLine class="mt-sm-n1 text-center"><small>(Default)</small></div>
            </div>
            <div class="cancel-button">
                <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">X</mat-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
</mat-basic-chip>
```

css is more illustative and could be modified for your criteries and used framework specifications, the main idea is in template layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example:

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
          [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
           {{ fruit.type }}
           <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
```